# Upload site on Heroku: Host key verification failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, ssh

The first time I unloaded a site on Heroku I faced many mistakes. How to correct?

```
k@k-Aspire-5750G:~/q$ git clone git@github.com:priroda/programmer-site
Cloning into 'programmer-site'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**I have 2 files in directory ssh:**

```
k@k-Aspire-5750G:~/.ssh$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

**`ssh`**

Your problem here looks like you're trying to `ssh` into `heroku` and `clone` your repo directly from `github`?

The problem here is that if you connect to `github` through `ssh` (a third party), you will basically have to create an authenticity token ([`ssh key`](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)), so that your third party machine is able to connect to your `github` repo

--

**Fix**

Typically, your local machine will be authenticated anyway when you install `git`, `heroku` not so. I would therefore recommend you push to `Heroku` from your local machine, rather than trying to clone through `github`:

```
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Heroku Deploy"
$ git push heroku master
```

If you do this first time, you will likely come back with some sort of request for your `ssh` to be accepted or something - just accept & it should push to `Heroku` from your local machine

[Here is Heroku's take on the matter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Answer (score 1):

Your output looks like a problem with your host verification with Github.com when you're trying to clone and nothing to do with Heroku.

Have a look in your ~/.ssh/known_hosts for a github.com entry and highlight it and remove it. Then try your clone again and it will prompt to verify, say yes and then it should clone successfully.

Comment: I have in ssh directory only 2 files: id_rsa  id_rsa.pub. There is no file know_hosts.